# Confusion about default initialisation of objects in Python

Tags: python

I do not understand what goes wrong with the following code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, val = [0, 1]):
        self.val = val
    def giveout(self):
        print(self.val)
    def swap(self):
        inter = self.val[0]
        self.val[0] = self.val[1]
        self.val[1] = inter
        

a = MyClass()
a.swap()
a.giveout()
b = MyClass()
b.giveout()
```

Output:

```
[1, 0]
[1, 0]
```

Why is the output not:

```
[1, 0]
[0, 1]
```

When b gets initialised without a parameter, should it not get `[0, 1]` as default parameter? When I replace `swap()` by:

```
 def swap(self):
        self.val = [self.val[1], self.val[0]]
```

Then the output is as I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem of initialization the default.
So describe what happens is that when python sees your class it creates a single `val` list which every other object refers to. So to get rid of this issue, never give `[]` or `{}` as default argument, use `None` then inside `__init__` initialize.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, val = None):
        self.val = [0, 1] if val is None else val
    def giveout(self):
        print(self.val)
    def swap(self):
        inter = self.val[0]
        self.val[0] = self.val[1]
        self.val[1] = inter
        

a = MyClass()
a.swap()
a.giveout()
b = MyClass()
b.giveout()
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me link another answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: +1. Holy crap! I never realized that you had to be that careful about intializing variables in __init__. Yikes. Makes me wonder how many times I've made this mistake.